# SSL Certificate error in Google SDK utilities

Tags: python, linux, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

We host our public web site on an Linux server in our office.  Last week I replaced the self-signed SSL certificate with a CA signed one.  After I did that I was unable to use the Google Cloud SDK utilities like gcloud or gsutil on my home Linux server. I get a traceback ending in

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 272, in match_hostname %
(hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames)))) 
ssl.CertificateError:
hostname 'metadata.google.internal' doesn't match either of
'www.rubgrp.com', 'rubgrp.com'
```

While rubgrp.com is the company domain name, there's no reference to it in my home SDK configuration - the Cloud account is associated with my personal gmail.com address.  To verify that the problem was associated with changing the office server certificate, I reinstalled the self-signed one and the error disappeared; it reappeared after putting back the signed certificate.

I tried installing the SDK on a Linux box in the office with the same version of the OS and Python, and it worked.  I tried installing it on a Mac at home, and it worked.  But when I set up another user on the home Linux box, that failed.  It acts like something is cached on he home server, but I can't find what or where.

Thanks!

Comment: did you muck at all with your /etc/hosts or dns resolving settings on your home linux?

If you claim that there is otherwise no reference to rubgrp.com in your sdk settings, it is odd that your office linux server would be contacted at all.

I assume "www.rubgrp.com" and "rubgrp.com" are the subject CN and subject alternate names found in the CA-issued certificate served by your office server.

Comment: I think that's a big part of it.  Not sure this qualifies as mucking, but the home resolver settings do include a default domain of rubgrp.com.  So I can see that in looking up metadata.google.internal it would add rubgrp.com, retrieve the new cert, then find metadata... wasn't  included.  But why doesn't an identically configured server in the office do the same.  I'm not disagreeing, I'm puzzled - I feel there's some key piece of this I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue too, I fixed it by editing `google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce_cache.py`:

Add a `return False` to the first line of the `GetOnGCE` function definition. This will prevent it from querying metadata.google.internal and getting confused.